# roleDelete event having problems after leaving guild

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

This error has appeared after I added a `.catch` statement to `Promises` after sending messages to guilds.

Quick Explanation: My bot is trying to retrieve data from a guild it no longer belongs to.

Here's my code:

**Filename: roleDelete.js**

```
'use strict';

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Error = require('debug')('Event:roleDelete:Error');

/**
 * @param {object} client - The client instance
 * @param {object} role - The deleted role object
*/

module.exports.run = (client, role) => {
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
  const guildID = role.guild.id;
  const guildName = role.guild.name;
  const guildIcon = role.guild.iconURL;
  const modLog = client.guilds.get(guildID).channels.find('name', client.config.modLog);
  const tempIcon = 'https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/ouGhEoGzz1ZyBG9mMFrYClvdv9V0FZ0jGSEHa_kLLYk/https/discordapp.com/assets/0e291f67c9274a1abdddeb3fd919cbaa.png';

  if (!modLog) return;

  embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(guildName, guildIcon ? guildIcon : tempIcon)
    .addField('Role Name', role.name, true)
    .addField('Role Color', role.hexColor, true)
    .addField('Role Hoisted', role.hoist, true)
    .setFooter('Role Deleted At')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(client.config.colors.red);

  return modLog.send(embed).catch(err => Error(err));
};
```

**Additional Info:**

```
bufferutil: 3.0.3
chalk: 2.3.0
clear: 0.0.1
debug: 3.1.0
discord.js: 11.3.0
dotenv: 4.0.0
firebase-admin: 5.8.1
moment: 2.20.1
opusscript: 0.0.6
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Discord.JS ignores and no error is thrown.
```

**Current Result:**

```
2018-01-23T12:34:05.029Z Event:guildDelete Left Guild: 395928739201941506, removed into database. 
2018-01-23T12:34:05.212Z Event:roleDelete:Error DiscordAPIError: Missing Access 
     at item.request.gen.end (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:71:65) 
     at then (/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:218:21) 
     at <anonymous> 
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) 
2018-01-23T12:34:05.255Z Event:guildMemberRemove:Error DiscordAPIError: Missing Access 
     at item.request.gen.end (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/rest/RequestHandlers/Sequential.js:71:65) 
     at then (/app/node_modules/snekfetch/src/index.js:218:21) 
     at <anonymous> 
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7
```

Is there any way to ignore the fact that it has left and completely ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an error with multiple events running asynchronously. If that is the case, a simple check if the client is still in the guild should fix the issue. An example of *one* of the few ways to do this can be found below.

```
const guild = bot.guilds.get(myguildid); // Should return null if the guild is not found
if (!guild) // The guild does not exist.
```

The property used can be found [here in the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds). Of course, there are other ways to do this, but this also sounds like a bug with the library and caching. If this causes any further bugs and the above does not fix the issue, try reporting the issue in more detail on the [Discord](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9) (to find and identify the bug). From there, they'll direct you to report it to their GitHub if it does turn out to be a bug. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked. I've actually had that fix in my mind and deployed before. But didn't know it was the patch for that error as well! Thank you anyway :D